# Ajax post special characters after serializing a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

AJAX code:

```
var data = $('#myIDform').serializeObject();
        $.post(
                'my url',
                {data: data},
                function(response){
                    response
                });
```

The serializeObject() function:  (I took it from a similar post in here)

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

I don't have any kind of parsing or stringify method or so, and whenever I add a new entry on my db with special characters (e.g. 'ñ') it shows perfectly in the response, but the database saves this: 'Ã±' 
I am not sure the problem is in the database, because the same thing without AJAX, works.

EDIT: When I manually refresh the page it shows as the database, since it's where the data is taken

I have been reading over here and JSON.parse and JSON.stringify dosen't seem to work for me, because I get something strange in the database: '{'I guess I am not doing it correctly or something is working not as intended.

In the .php i parsed it as:  `$result = $obj->insert ( JSON_parse($_POST['data']) );`

And in the .js i strigified it as: `var data = JSON.stringify($('#myIDform').serializeObject();`

How it looks like in the database: http://prntscr.com/99t6po

EDIT: SOLVED. Database and PHP were in different charsets

Comment: Also: What database are you using and what is its encoding set to?

Comment: What encoding are you using in javascript, php and the database